# How do I stop typing the last 'else' twice?

Tags: php

Exercising my php, I came across this, code working, but how do I stop typing the last 'else' twice? What is the correct form?

my code:

```
if ( wp_date('d') == get_the_date('d') ) {

    $status = get_youtube_status( get_sub_field( 'link' ) );

    if ( !empty( $status['init'] ) ) {

        $init = $status['init'];
        $views = get_youtube_views( $status['views'] );
        echo '
            <div class="status">
                <div class="nowlive">AGORA AO VIVO</div>
                <div class="time">Live iniciada há '.get_youtube_time( $init ).'</div>
                <div class="views">'.$views.' assistindo agora</div>
            </div>
        ';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="date"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> '.get_sub_field( 'date' ).'</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<div class="date"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> '.get_sub_field( 'date' ).'</div>';
}
```

Comment: I would wrap everything in a try-catch statement and do the else part in the catch. But you'd have to change the conditionals, obviously, and you'd end up with no else's whatsoever and only 1st level indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define and make a default echo

```
$return = '<div class="date"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> '.get_sub_field( 'date' ).'</div>';
if ( wp_date('d') == get_the_date('d') ) {

    $status = get_youtube_status( get_sub_field( 'link' ) );

    if ( !empty( $status['init'] ) ) {

        $init = $status['init'];
        $views = get_youtube_views( $status['views'] );
        $return = '
            <div class="status">
                <div class="nowlive">AGORA AO VIVO</div>
                <div class="time">Live iniciada há '.get_youtube_time( $init ).'</div>
                <div class="views">'.$views.' assistindo agora</div>
            </div>
        ';
    } 
}
echo $return;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean flag:

```
$flag = false;

if ( wp_date('d') == get_the_date('d') ) {
    $status = get_youtube_status( get_sub_field( 'link' ) );

    if ( !empty( $status['init'] ) ) {
        $flag = true;
        $init = $status['init'];
        $views = get_youtube_views( $status['views'] );
        echo '
            <div class="status">
                <div class="nowlive">AGORA AO VIVO</div>
                <div class="time">Live iniciada há '.get_youtube_time( $init ).'</div>
                <div class="views">'.$views.' assistindo agora</div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}

if (!$flag) {
    echo '<div class="date"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> '.get_sub_field( 'date' ).'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move it to the end and encapsulate it in a single if statement:

```
if ( wp_date('d') == get_the_date('d') ) {

    $status = get_youtube_status( get_sub_field( 'link' ) );

    if ( !empty( $status['init'] ) ) {

        $init = $status['init'];
        $views = get_youtube_views( $status['views'] );
        echo '
            <div class="status">
                <div class="nowlive">AGORA AO VIVO</div>
                <div class="time">Live iniciada há '.get_youtube_time( $init ).'</div>
                <div class="views">'.$views.' assistindo agora</div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}

if ( wp_date('d') != get_the_date('d') || empty( $status['init'] )) {
    echo '<div class="date"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> '.get_sub_field( 'date' ).'</div>';
}
```