# How to format date and time in PHP function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I am using a plugin to manage registrations to events (the plugin name is Events Manager Pro).

With this plugin, we are allowed to create placeholders to display various information on events webpages.

I created a placeholder to show the date and time when registrations to an event starts. The name I gave to my placeholder is: #_REGISTRATIONSTARTDATETIME

I use this code in the function.php file of my child theme:

```
function my_em_registrationstartdatetime_placeholder($replace, $EM_Event, $result){
    if ( $result == '#_REGISTRATIONSTARTDATETIME' ) {
        $ticket_list = "";
        foreach( $EM_Event->get_tickets()->tickets as $EM_Ticket ){
          $ticket_list .= $EM_Ticket->get_datetime('start');
        }
        $replace = $ticket_list;
    }
    return $replace;
}
add_filter('em_event_output_placeholder','my_em_registrationstartdatetime_placeholder',1,3);
```

My problem is the date and time is output in this format: 2023-01-09 10:00:00

I wish to have the date and time output in this format instead: Monday January 9 at 10h00

Thank you!

My knowledge in PHP is limited. I am sorry, but I am eager to learn. Does anyone know what could be modified in my PHP code to format the date and time?

Comment: you can use the_time function of wordpress. You can find more info here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/

Comment: Related: [How to get timestamp based on wordpress setting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67208848/2943403)

Comment: Related: [Wordpress wrong timezone in timestamp tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69243816/2943403) and [PHP: minus 2 days excluding weekends and holidays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71986788/2943403) and [How do I stop typing the last 'else' twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61334560/2943403) and [Datetime value different from timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73476433/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`wp_date`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/) function and php [date format parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters)

```
$replace = wp_date('l F j \a\t G\hi', strtotime($ticket_list));
```

to add a timezone to it, add a [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) argument to the function. For example:

```
$replace = wp_date('l F j \a\t G\hi', strtotime($ticket_list), new DateTimeZone('America/Vancouver'));
```

Comment: It works with `$replace = wp_date('l F j \a\t G\hi', strtotime($ticket_list));`. But, there is one last thing. The time is off by 4 hours. I guess there is somewhere I need to mention the timezone?

Comment: updated my answer with timezone control

Comment: by default `wp_date()` calls the timezone set in Settings > General using the `wp_timezone()` function

Comment: There is something strange. In WordPress in Settings > General, I have New York as timezone. I am located in Montreal, Qc (Canada). Which is in straight vertical line with New York, NY. The plugin I am using (Events Manager Pro) has also a setting for timezone and it is set to New York. I use `$replace = wp_date('l F j \a\t G\hi', strtotime($ticket_list), new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));`. I get a delay of 4 hours. If I reverse back to `$replace = $ticket_list;`, the time is correct, but the format goes back to 2023-01-09 10:00:00. Which is the right time, but not the right format.

Comment: might be the `strtotime` function playing up. [check out this link](https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/wordpress-timezones-strtotime-date-functions/)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. It now works.

Here is the code I have in my functions.php file :

```
function my_em_registrationstartdatetime_placeholder($replace, $EM_Event, $result){
    if ( $result == '#_REGISTRATIONSTARTDATETIME' ) {
        $ticket_list = "";
        foreach( $EM_Event->get_tickets()->tickets as $EM_Ticket ){
          $ticket_list = $EM_Ticket->get_datetime('start');
        }
        $replace = wp_date('l j F \a\t G\hi', wp_strtotime($ticket_list));
    }
    return $replace;
}
add_filter('em_event_output_placeholder','my_em_registrationstartdatetime_placeholder',1,3);
```

In the functions.php file, I also added the code recommended in the link suggested by Moishy : https://mediarealm.com.au/articles/wordpress-timezones-strtotime-date-functions/.